# Google Drive API not returning parents for files

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-client

I started messing around with the Google Drive API for ruby (using the google-api-client gem) and I immediately ran into a problem. I can return all the files just fine, but their `parents` property is nil, even for files that are in a sub folder in my drive. The way I understand it, `parents` should contain the list of folders that this file resides in. I have full drive scope, so that shouldn't be an issue.

Is this a bug in the gem or am I doing something wrong? The relevant part of the code looks like this :

```
service = Google::Apis::DriveV3::DriveService.new
service.client_options.application_name = APPLICATION_NAME
service.authorization = authorize

response = service.list_files
response.files.each do |file|
  puts "#{file.name} (#{file.parents})"
end
```

Comment: you need to specifically request which properties of the file resource are returned. By default, file.parents isn't one of them.

Comment: @pinoyyid And how do I do that? I can't seem to find anything about that in the docs. I'm using V3, by the way

Comment: The [Search for files](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) guide has a Ruby example that demonstrates setting the field mask for which properties are returned.

Comment: Never mind, I just found it : The correct line would be `response = service.list_files(fields: "files(id, name, parents)")` . Thank you.

Comment: @Max, I have no idea how you found that, but thank you!